# Learning C++ Example Problems

Tags: c++

I am currently going though the process of learning C++ though reading programming books. I understand the concept but find a few days after reading, the concepts start to drift from my memory.

The only thing that keeps them there is working through examples/questions.

Are there any good sites or books that can be recommend which give a large number of examples/questions to work through, with explanations of what each example should help you learn?

Comment: Might be a good idea to read a good book, rather than that nonsense - take a look at Accelerated C++ by Koenig & Moo.

Comment: VC++6 is a decade old. It's a piece of junk, and any book that specifically targets *that* is fundamentally flawed (both because it's so obsolete, and because good books talk about the C++ language in general, not *specific* versions of *specific* compilers)

Comment: The reason I chose the book is because Visual C++ 6 is what is used within the company. The book has been a useful starting block although I am looking to broaden my horizon in terms of understanding C++. I have taken a look at the Koenig and Moo book, on Amazon it has great reviews so I will consider ordering that.

Comment: @RisingCascade: When learning something new, I always try to not to end up learning someone's way to see, use, and teach it. Using a VC6 book is the opposite of this. Plus it deals with a compiler that >10 years old and has, for most of its life-time, been dissed for being unable to compile C++ code that was modern 10 years ago and thus preventing use of great "new" techniques. As for "Accelerated C++": Make sure you're OK with a quite faced-paced introduction and a steep learning curve. Other than that, it's a very great book which put teaching C++ back onto its feet.

Comment: @sbi I think it unfair to crticise VC++6, which actually came out before the C++ Standard was ratified, and at the time was pretty damn good.

Comment: @Neil: VC6 came out in 1998, the year the standard was ratified. While all other vendors tried to track the std evolving as close as possible without having to redo things too often (I remember Borland having an early version of the string class in the beginning of the 90ies), MS at that time lost their vote in the std committee because they didn't attend meetings for a very long time. I was working on strictly cross-platform stuff back then, and until VC7.1 appeared, VC6 stole _endless amounts of time_ for porting, mainly because it basically chokes as soon as the keyword `template` appeares.

Comment: @sbi "All the vendors tried to track the standard" - hollow laughter - I take it you have never used one of Sun's compilers? And as for Borland having a string implementation in the early 90s, so what? I personally wrote about three of the things.

Comment: @Neil: I only had the pleasure to (help someone to) use the Sun's compiler five years ago. So maybe they're about as bad. How does that make the rest of my statement about VC6 wrong? And where did you write about which three of what things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your books don't give you tasks to chew on, get better books.

Look at those mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231942/learning-c-without-an-ide/1232035#1232035).

Comment: Thanks sbi, I will get some of the books mentioned and see how my coding improves.

Answer (score 4):

[This site](http://www.eit.ihk-edu.dk/subjects/cpp/) and [this site](http://www.functionx.com/cpp/examples/index.htm) may be worth looking for you.

Answer (score 2):

You're right. Reading books is not likely to help unless you practice what you learn.

You didn't say what kind of examples you need, and obviously it's important to choose examples which mean something to you - that is, applications which you can see the value of.

Can you suggest some topics which interest you? Like business applications or games, scientific or otherwise?

Comment: Business applications would be the main area of interest, I am especially interested in the application of Object Orientated programming to business.

Comment: Ah, business applications are not my area of expertise, so I should defer to the other excellent suggestions. I can only add ... choose the book wisely.

Comment: I believe it's best if the examples fit to the subjects taught -- which is why it's so important the books teaching come with good examples. But, yes, "Reading books is not likely to help unless you practice what you learn." +1

Comment: @RisingCascade: C++ is a multi-paradigm language and it's strongest where it mixes OO with generic programming, functional programming, and other fascinating techniques. If you mostly focus on OO, you'll miss a lot of where it shines. (I'd even say you miss the best, but that's debatable.)

Answer (score 0):

Just for coment, some examples, i trying add some code....

```
  #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <list>
    #include <vector>
    #include <set>
    #include <map>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <iostream> 

    using namespace std;

    bool Porovnej(int &p1) {
        if (p1 > 5)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    struct osoba{
        int vek;
        string jmeno;
        set<char> mnozinaPismen;
    public:
        void Vypis();
    };

    void osoba::Vypis() {
        cout << vek << endl;
        cout << jmeno << endl;
        for (auto m : mnozinaPismen){
            cout << m << endl;
        }
        cout << "" << endl;
    };

    int Vytrid(int &prvek) {
        if(prvek !=30){
            return prvek;
        }
        return -(prvek);
    }

    struct JaKralJeliman{
        int vek;
        string jmeno;
        string titul;
    public:
        void Vypis();
    };

    void JaKralJeliman::Vypis() {
        cout << vek << endl;
        cout << titul << endl;
        cout << jmeno << endl;

    }


    class Vytridit{
    public:
        int operator()(int &prvek) const{
            if (prvek > 2) {
                return prvek;
            }
        }
    };

    int Pricti(int &prvek){
        prvek = prvek + 1;
        return prvek;
    }


    class NasobeniHodnot { 
    private:  int _hodnota;
    public:  NasobeniHodnot(int hodnota) :_hodnota(hodnota) {} 
             void operator() (int &prvek) const { prvek *= _hodnota; }
    };

    int GenerujPrvky(){
        int prvek = 0;
        prvek += rand();

        return prvek;
    }


    class Pair { 
    private:  
        int _key, _value;  
    public:      
        int GetKey() const { return _key; } 
        int GetValue() const { return _value; }   
        void SetKey(int key) { _key = key; }   
        void SetValue(int value) { _value = value; } 
    };

    istream& operator>>(istream &is, Pair &objekt) {
        int cislo;   
        is >> cislo; /* Využiji již přetížených   operátorů pro primitivní datové   typy.*/    
        objekt.SetKey(cislo);  
        is >> cislo;   
        objekt.SetValue(cislo);   
        return is;
    }

    ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Pair &objekt) { 
        os << objekt.GetKey() << objekt.GetValue();    
        return os;
    }

    int main()
    {
        vector<int> v;
        vector<int>::iterator it;
        vector<int> v2(100);
        vector<int> v3(10);


        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            v.push_back(i+1);
        }

        it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), 5);
        cout << *it << endl;

        back_inserter(v) = 30;
        back_inserter(v) = 32;
        back_inserter(v) = 32;
        back_inserter(v) = 30;
        back_inserter(v) = 30;

        v.reserve(2 * v.size()); 
        copy(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(v));
        copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    //  for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout));

        it = min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
        it = max_element(v.begin(), v.end());

        int pocetTricitek = count(v.begin(), v.end(), 30);

        cout << "Pocet hodnoty 30 v kontejneru v je:" << pocetTricitek << endl;
        cout << "Nejvetsi hodnota" << *it <<endl;

        it = find_if(v.begin(), v.end()-1, Porovnej);
        cout << "Hodnota iteratoru:" << *it << endl;

        it = search_n(v.begin(), v.end()-1, 3, 32);
        cout << "Hodnota iteratoru:" << *it << endl;

        transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v2.begin(), Vytrid);

        fill_n(v3.begin(), 5, 10);

        replace(v.begin(), v.end(), 30, 1);             //nahradí číslo 30 číslem 1

        reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
        rotate(v.begin(), v.begin() + 3, v.end());

        sort(v.begin(), v.end());
        //partial_sort(v.begin(), v.begin() + 10, v.end());


        it = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 15);   //>= než 15

        vector<int> kolekce(10);
        generate(kolekce.begin(), kolekce.end(), GenerujPrvky);

        NasobeniHodnot nh(2);
        for_each(kolekce.begin(), kolekce.end(), nh);
        for_each(kolekce.begin(), kolekce.end(), NasobeniHodnot(2));

        int c = 1000, b = 9;  
        cout << setw(3) << "b=" << b << endl << "c=" << c << endl;  
        cout << setw(3) << setfill('@') << hex << "c=" << c;
        cout << endl;


        Pair pair;  
        cin >> pair;    
        cout << "Objekt byl:" << endl << pair;


        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }


/*String

string s = "ahoj Oldo";
string::size_type idx;
int pocet = 0;
string s2("Ahoj karle", 6);
cout << s2;

idx = s.find("o");

cout << "idx:" << idx << "string s:" << s << endl;
if (idx == std::string::npos) {
cout << "Není obsažen v řetězci";
} else{
cout << "Je obsažen v řetězci na pozici:" << idx;
}


--------------------//////////////---------------------------
Kontejnery:

string pole[] = { "2", "50" ,"99", "1000" };
list<string> seznam(pole, pole+sizeof(pole)/sizeof(pole[0]));

vector<string> vektorRetezcu;
vektorRetezcu.push_back("a");
vektorRetezcu.push_back("b");
vektorRetezcu.push_back("c");
vektorRetezcu.push_back("d");
vektorRetezcu.push_back("e");
vektorRetezcu.push_back("e");
vektorRetezcu.push_back("a");

list<string> seznam2(vektorRetezcu.begin(), vektorRetezcu.end());

for (auto s : seznam2)
{
cout << s << endl;
}

swap(seznam, seznam2);

for (auto s : seznam2)
{
cout << s << endl;
}


string s1 = "ahoj";
string s2 = "olda";

cout << s1 << s2 << endl;


swap(s1, s2);
cout << s1 << s2 << endl;


--------------------////////////-/////----------------
List
list<osoba> listOsob;
osoba clovek;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{

cout << "Zadej cloveka:" << endl;
cin >> clovek.jmeno;
cin >> clovek.prijmeni;
cin >> clovek.vek;
listOsob.push_back(clovek);


}

for  (auto osoby : listOsob)
{
cout << "Clovek cislo " << endl;
cout << osoby.jmeno << endl;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////---------------------mnozicn
struct osoba{
int vek;
string jmeno;
set<char> mnozinaPismen;
public:
void Vypis();
};

void osoba::Vypis() {
cout << vek;
cout << jmeno;
for (auto m : mnozinaPismen)
{
cout << m << endl;
}

}

int main()
{
vector<osoba> vectorLidi;
osoba clovek;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
cin >> clovek.vek;
cin >> clovek.jmeno;
for (int i = 0; i < clovek.jmeno.length(); i++)
{
clovek.mnozinaPismen.insert(clovek.jmeno[i]);
}
vectorLidi.push_back(clovek);
}

for (auto v : vectorLidi)
{
v.Vypis();
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}






-----------------////////////-------------------

vector<osoba> vectorLidi;
osoba clovek;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
cin >> clovek.vek;
cin >> clovek.jmeno;
for (int i = 0; i < clovek.jmeno.length(); i++)
{
clovek.mnozinaPismen.insert(clovek.jmeno[i]);
}
vectorLidi.push_back(clovek);
}

cout << "Nacte no -------------" << endl;


for (auto v : vectorLidi)
{
v.Vypis();
}




*/
```